# Redux and useEffect on page reload

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-hooks

I have react app and I'm using redux in order to manage state.

**What suppose to happen:**

Redux holds an object that contains an `_id` string, and on a page I have a `useEffect` that first checks that checks `_id` is not an empty string and only after, invokes an async function `onPlantTimelineMount()` to fetch data using the `_id`.
When a user reloads the page, Redux state is default loaded where `_id` is an empty string so the if statement inside the `useEffect` is invoked, to fetch that item using a different async function `ifUserRefreshPage()`, dispatch the item to Redux state, and only after invoke `onPlantTimelineMount()`.

**The Problem:**

The `ifUserRefreshPage()` successfully fetches the data and dispatch it to Redux state, but the `onPlantTimelineMount()` still uses the state prior to the `ifUserRefreshPage()` invocation - which means that `_id` is still an empty string.

**Worth mentioning:**

Inside `ifUserRefreshPage()` I serialize the fetched item (line 38), I dispatch it to Redux (line 39), console.log the fetched item (line 40 in the image), and I console.log the item in Redux state (line 41) and its still empty!!!!!!
HOW???

[image]

**The Code:**

```
const currentPlant = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.currentPlant)
    const plantUpdates = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.currentPlant.updates)
    const reduxPlants = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.plants)
    const location = useLocation();
    const { show: showSnackbar, component: snackBar } = useSnackbar();
    async function ifUserRefreshPage() {
        setIsFetching(true)
        const plantId = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
        try {
            console.log(`ifUserRefreshPage invoked`);
            const plantResponse = await fetchPlantById(plantId, '1')
            const serializedPlant = plantManager.serializePlant(plantResponse.data)  // line 38
            dispatch(setCurrentPlant(serializedPlant))                               // line 39
            console.log(serializedPlant);                                            // line 40
            console.log(currentPlant);                                               // line 41
            const gardenResponse = await fetchMyGarden('1')
            dispatch(addPlants(plantManager.serializeGarden(gardenResponse.data)))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`error while running ifUserRefreshPage function` + err);
            showSnackbar("Failed to load Timeline", "error");
        } finally {
            setIsFetching(false)
        }
    }

    async function onPlantTimelineMount() {
        setIsFetching(true)
        console.log(`ifUserRefreshPage invoked`);
        try {
            const response = await fetchPlantUpdates(currentPlant._id!)
            if (response.success) {
                dispatch(setUpdatesToCurrentPlant(plantUpdateManager.serializeUpdatesArray(response.data)))
            }
        } catch (err) {
            showSnackbar("Failed to load Timeline", "error");
        } finally {
            setIsFetching(false)
        }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function start() {
            if (!currentPlant._id) {
                await ifUserRefreshPage()
            }
           await onPlantTimelineMount()
        }
        start()
    },[])
```

Comment: You are not passing `currentPlant` to your `useEffect` deps array

Comment: that will cause an infinite loop... but thanks anyways someone helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I console.log the item in Redux state (line 41) and its still empty!!!!!! HOW???

Because that's a local constant. It can **never** change. It's similar to the common issue that updating state does not change your local variables. [Stack overflow on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately), [React docs on this topic](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)

When you dispatch your action, you update the redux store. This updated state could be accessed by calling `store.getState()`, though that's not typically something you would do directly in a react app. You've called `const currentPlant = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.currentPlant)`, which subscribes to the store, and so the change of state causes your component to rerender. When this rerender happens a new local constant will be created with the new value, but your code from the previous render has no access to this. Your `console.log(currentPlant);` from the previous render will only ever log out the old value.

Since you do have the new value in a different variable, i recommend you use that. Eg, modify `ifUserRefreshPage` to return the new plant:

```
async function ifUserRefreshPage() {
  setIsFetching(true);
  const plantId = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  try {
    console.log(`ifUserRefreshPage invoked`);
    const plantResponse = await fetchPlantById(plantId, "1");
    const serializedPlant = plantManager.serializePlant(plantResponse.data);
    dispatch(setCurrentPlant(serializedPlant));
    const gardenResponse = await fetchMyGarden("1");
    dispatch(addPlants(plantManager.serializeGarden(gardenResponse.data)));
    return serializedPlant; // <--------------Added return
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`error while running ifUserRefreshPage function` + err);
    showSnackbar("Failed to load Timeline", "error");
  } finally {
    setIsFetching(false);
  }
}
```

And modify `onPlantTimelineMount` so you can pass in the plant:

```
//              Added argument -----VVVVV
async function onPlantTimelineMount(plant) {
  setIsFetching(true);
  console.log(`ifUserRefreshPage invoked`);
  try {
    const response = await fetchPlantUpdates(plant._id!);
    if (response.success) {
      dispatch(
        setUpdatesToCurrentPlant(
          plantUpdateManager.serializeUpdatesArray(response.data),
        ),
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showSnackbar("Failed to load Timeline", "error");
  } finally {
    setIsFetching(false);
  }
}
```

And update your effect to connect the two:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function start() {
    let plant = currentPlant;
    if (!plant._id) {
      plant = await ifUserRefreshPage();
    }
    await onPlantTimelineMount(plant);
  }
  start();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. that worked exactly like I wanted.